# Multiple matches in a list

Tags: python

I attempt to take elements icluding `find` `index` and `count` from a list of string methods.

```
x = ['endswith', 'rjust', 'split', 'lower', 'swapcase',
'replace', 'title', 'splitlines', 'capitalize', 'format_map',
'maketrans', 'translate', 'partition', 'expandtabs', 'rstrip', 's
trip', 'zfill', 'startswith', 'encode', 'center', 'lstrip',
'format', 'casefold', 'rpartition', 'ljust', 'rsplit',
 'join', 'upper']
```

Use `endswith` to filter them:

```
>>> [ i for i in x if i.endswith(('find', 'index', 'count'))]
['rindex', 'rfind', 'count', 'index', 'find']
```

Alternatively I try `in`,but fail to output:

```
>>> [ i for i in x if ('find', 'index', 'count') in x]
[]
>>> [ i for i in x if ('find', 'index', 'count') in i]
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

It works with chain logic operations:

```
>>> [ i for i in x if 'find' in i or 'index' in i or 'count' in i ]
['rindex', 'rfind', 'count', 'index', 'find']
```

How to get `[ i for i in x if ('a', 'b', 'c') in i]` working?

Comment: `('find', 'index', 'count') in something` tests if **that whole tuple** is present in `something`. That's not what you want to test for, is it?

Comment: get your idea now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the builtin `any` to test if any of the items is contained in the string:

```
items = ('find', 'index', 'count')
lst = [i for i in x if any(j in i for j in items)]
```

Comment: `(j in i for j in items)` , a tuple comprehension?

Comment: no a _generator comprehension_. No need to build a list to pass to `any`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[i for i in x if any(map(lambda x: x in y, ['index', 'count', 'find']))]
```

Comment: `map(lambda x: x in y,`: ouch, cumbersome.

Comment: i always get the cumbersome comment for map.... guess i should switch to generators :(